# Handling Visual Studio 2010 events

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vspackage, visual-studio-sdk

Is it possible to handle Visual Studio events?
For example, to perform some operations when the user opens the Toolbox.

Using VS2010 SDK how can I do something like this?

Also, how do i know that Visual Studio is still initializing and it is loading packages programmatically?

And how to know programmatically that Visual Studio loaded all packages and now it is ready for users interaction? I am more looking for VisualStudio events like LoadingPackagesEvent, AllPackagesLoadedEvent.. or something similar!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

- Datte

Answer (score 0):

To know when a window has been open (created) on Visual studio you can hook [EnvDTE.WindowEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.windowevents.aspx)

For when VS is ready you can listen on [DTEEventsClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yaf2yxc2.aspx) events

However some VSIX are marked as deferred load or just load under specific conditions

Comment: I have tried both. Unfortunately, EnvDTE.WindowEvents does not fire for the Toolbox Window. DTEEventsClass events are not getting fired if they are hooked on from within the Package!

Comment: There are two ways more, but they are large to explain if you are still interested on this question, let me know and I'll develop the answer...